# How to properly include a declaration file with module augmentation in an npm package written in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have an npm package -- `tyranid-gracl` [(link)](https://github.com/tyranid-org/tyranid-gracl) -- written in typescript and extending another package: `tyranid` [(link)](https://github.com/tyranid-org/tyranid), written in javascript but [including type definitions](https://github.com/tyranid-org/tyranid/blob/master/src/tyranid.d.ts).

Within `tyranid-gracl` I use [module augmentation to extend several interfaces in tyranid](https://github.com/tyranid-org/tyranid-gracl/blob/master/src/tyranid-extensions.d.ts). Additionally, I've exposed the `.d.ts` files generated for `tyranid-gracl` in the `typings` field of `package.json` in order to allow 3rd-party typescript libraries to have the typings for `tyranid-gracl`.

**Question:** How can I properly expose the module augmentation of `tyranid` made by `tyranid-gracl` to a 3rd library that installs `tyranid-gracl` via npm?

**Basic distillation of the problem**

Type definition file for first library `tyranid`:

```
/**
*  Type definitions for tyranid.js
*/
export = TyrStatic;

declare namespace TyrStatic {

  // declare properties of Tyr object
  export namespace Tyr {

    interface Document {
      $id: string;
    }

  }
}
```

Module extension by second library, `tyranid-gracl`

```
import { documentMethods as dm } from './tyranid/documentMethods';

declare module 'tyranid' {

  namespace Tyr {
    /**
    * Add additional methods to Document interface
    */
    interface Document {
      $allow: typeof dm.$allow;
      $deny: typeof dm.$deny;
    }
  }

}
```

I want the above modifications to occur when a developer installs `tyranid-gracl` via npm. Currently, I have a reference in `index.d.ts` of `tyranid-gracl` to the above modification, but it does not seem to work -- specifically, the added methods do not appear visible to the type system.

Hope that makes sense -- thanks in advance!

Comment: On first glance, aren't you missing `export` for `namespace Tyr` in your `tyranid-gracl` typings?

Comment: the above works locally. I think for augmenting an existing namespace, the augmentation file doesn't export (or it overwrites?), at least that was what seemed to happen for me.

Comment: @BenSouthgate Sorry for the late comment. But maybe you remember: did you manage to solve this?